# Permit nested resource creation in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app a user has a setting(s) object nested like so

```
resources :user do
  resource :setting
end
```

now everytime I create a setting, the setting is created but without the user id attached to it.
Presumably this is because of

```
def setting_params
  params.require(:setting).permit(:region, :publish_to, :language)
end
```

strips that off.

```
# GET /settings/new
def new
@setting = Setting.new
end

# GET /settings/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /settings
# POST /settings.json
def create
 @setting = Setting.new(setting_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @setting.save
    format.html { redirect_to user_setting_path(@setting, current_user), notice: 'Setting was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: user_setting_path }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @setting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

If I add `:user_id` to the line, nothing changes.

How can I attach the user here?

Comment: could you add the action block from the controller to your question

Comment: inside the create action, can you inspect if you have a param called `id` or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mohammad AbuShady: Not quite, but you helped me stumble over the solution! Thanks!!

You were right, `:user_id` was the right key to use.

Although (and please correct me if I am wrong here), just picking the user_id out of the params opens up the possibility of assigning settings to another user (by smuggling in a different user_id).

Since I am using a gem which allows me to find the current user by accessing the `current_user` method, my code works and now looks like this:

**Create**

```
@setting = User.find(params[:user_id]).create_setting(setting_params)
```

or with the supposedly "save" way

```
@setting = User.find(current_user).create_setting(setting_params)
```

So strangely, `.setting.new` did not work for me (settings didn't either) but the convenience `create_setting` did. Do you know why??

**Update**

```
def update
  #@setting = params[:setting]
  #@setting = current_user.setting
  #@setting = User.find(params[:user_id]).setting#.update(setting_params)
  @setting = User.find(current_user).setting
  respond_to do |format|
    if @setting.update(setting_params)
      format.html { redirect_to user_setting_path, notice: 'Setting was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: user_setting_path }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @setting.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna assume that you have a `params[:id]` if so you should change your create action to this

```
@setting = User.find(params[:id]).settings.new(setting_params)
```

if it's called `:user_id` then it would be

```
@setting = User.find(params[:user_id]).settings.new(setting_params)
```

This will set the foreign_key automatically in the new setting that's created

Comment: Surely it would be `:user_id` as it's a nested resource?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :settings #-> domain.com/users/:user_id/settings/new
end

#app/models/setting.rb
class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :settings
end

#app/controllers/settings_controller.rb
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @setting = current_user.settings.new
   end

   def create
     @setting = current_user.settings.new setting_params
     @setting.save
   end

   private

   def setting_params
      params.require(:setting).permit(:region, :publish_to, :language)
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to create the following view:

```
#app/views/settings/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [current_user, @setting] do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :region %>
   <%= f.text_field :publish_to %>
   <%= f.text_field :language %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Nested**

Nested models / data is somewhat tricky in Rails, mainly because of the way in which you should be able to send the required data through to your app.

The most commonly used [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) is only really valid if you want to create a record *through* the one you're working with (IE if you wanted to create a `User` AND a `Setting`), you'd be able to use it (I can detail at another time)

I believe the way I recommended will give you the results you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What you wrote here was basically what I already worked previously. Nevertheless the tricky part is that setting is a singular object which contains attributes representing the settings. BUT a user can only have ONE setting (object). How is this done?

Comment: Oh okay! You'll be best looking at Rails routing singular resources - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources